# React-native: error @jest/create-cache-key-function@27.4.2: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version

Tags: react-native

I am almost starter on react-native. Trying to create a new project but I get the below error. I am using Windows 7, latest applicable node version for my operating system is 13.14.0. Is it about this? Any help is appreciated.

```
[2/4] Fetching packages...
error @jest/create-cache-key-function@27.4.2: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected 
version "^10.13.0 || ^12.13.0 || ^14.15.0 || >=15.0.0". Got "13.14.0"
error Found incompatible module.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
Error: Command failed: yarn add react-native --exact
    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:611:11)
    at execSync (child_process.js:647:15)
    at run (C:\Users\SAMSUNG\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native-cli\index.js:294:5)
    at createProject (C:\Users\SAMSUNG\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native-cli\index.js:249:3)
    at init (C:\Users\SAMSUNG\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native-cli\index.js:200:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\SAMSUNG\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native-cli\index.js:153:7)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1118:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:982:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:875:14) {
  status: 1,
  signal: null,
  output: [ null, null, null ],
  pid: 9344,
  stdout: null,
  stderr: null
}
Command `yarn add react-native --exact` failed.
```

Comment: Yes but I dont remember, I think you should initialize the project by yarn init (not expo init), then the problem disappears

Comment: I answered as a post after I remembered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first line of the error, it is written that,

```
"Expected version "^10.13.0 || ^12.13.0 || ^14.15.0 || >=15.0.0"
```

so you Need to update Node version.